# Null Pointer Exception , Parcel.ReadException while sending SMS?

Tags: android, sms

I am working on an appliction in which I ahve to use SMS service. When I try to send SMS I get the following strange exception. Sometimes SMS is sent absolutely fine, but sometimes I get this exception. I don't know where i8es the problem. Following is the my code:

```
 String messageText = Util.getSMSText(myActivity.this, Util.CurrentLocation);
 messageText += "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + locationInfo.getLat() + "," + locationInfo.getLng();
 String number = guardian.getGuardianNumber();
 SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
 smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, text, null, null);
```

Following is the trace:

```
12-22 21:03:59.325: W/System.err(8140):     java.lang.NullPointerException
12-22 21:03:59.325: W/System.err(8140):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1328)
12-22 21:03:59.325: W/System.err(8140):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1276)
12-22 21:03:59.325: W/System.err(8140):     at com.android.internal.telephony.ISms$Stub$Proxy.sendTextOnSubscription(ISms.java:1096)
12-22 21:03:59.325: W/System.err(8140):     at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(SmsManager.java:149)
12-22 21:03:59.325: W/System.err(8140):     at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(SmsManager.java:89)
12-22 21:03:59.335: W/System.err(8140):     at com.invocode.sms.SMSManager.sendSMS(SMSManager.java:12)
12-22 21:03:59.335: W/System.err(8140):     at com.invocode.ui.iamhere.myActivity$2$2.onClick(myActivity.java:205)
```

Any help is appreciated ...

Comment: have you checked for the SEND_SMS permission. and whether there are some values in **number** or not.?

Comment: @SahilMahajanMj .. there are longitude and latitude value in the msg. And yes Permissions are there.

Comment: what's in **number** string and why you have used **MessageText** but in sendSMS, you have used **text**.?

Comment: that's just a string nothing else.

Comment: have you checked is there anyhting in the **number** string. It might be null.

Answer (score 0):

it can come if the sms sending number is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the codification of your strings... Same problem here. I'm testing and I don't get error when I send a simple String as "asadsdasd"

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar error when I was trying to use the test product for in-app billing, but my draft build wasn't in the market yet.

What I'm thinking is that the OS Cannot bind your service. It so happens that the service you're using is the os based one for contact info, but the service you're trying to use cannot be reached, validly.

Answer (score 0):

I found yet another reason to get this message.
If you use non-ascii characters in your message (e.g. U+02BC) than this NPE is also thrown.